# Ctypes: allocate double** , pass it to C, then use it in Python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, python-3.4, ctypes

**EDIT 3**

I have some C++ code (externed as C) which I access from python.
I want to allocate a `double**` in python, pass it to the C/C++ code to copy the content of a class internal data, and then use it in python similarly to how I would use a list of lists.

Unfortunately I can not manage to specify to python the size of the most inner array, so it reads invalid memory when iterating over it and the program segfaults.

I can not change the structure of the internal data in C++, and I'd like to have python do the bound checking for me (like if I was using a c_double_Array_N_Array_M instead of an array of pointers).

test.cpp (compile with `g++ -Wall -fPIC --shared -o test.so test.cpp` )

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

class Dummy
{
    double** ptr;
    int e;
    int i;
};

extern "C" {
    void * get_dummy(int N, int M) {
        Dummy * d = new Dummy();
        d->ptr = new double*[N];
        d->e = N;
        d->i = M;
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        {
            d->ptr[i]=new double[M];
            for(int j=0; j <M; ++j)
            {
                d->ptr[i][j] = i*N + j;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }

    void copy(void * inst, double ** dest) {
        Dummy * d = static_cast<Dummy*>(inst);
        for(int i=0; i < d->e; ++i)
        {
            memcpy(dest[i], d->ptr[i], sizeof(double) * d->i);
        }
    }

    void cleanup(void * inst) {
        if (inst != NULL) {
            Dummy * d = static_cast<Dummy*>(inst);
            for(int i=0; i < d->e; ++i)
            {
                delete[] d->ptr[i];
            }
            delete[] d->ptr;
            delete d;
        }
    }


}
```

Python (this segfaults. Put it in the same dir in which the test.so is)

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager
import ctypes as ct

DOUBLE_P = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)
library_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'test.so')
lib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(library_path)
lib.get_dummy.restype = ct.c_void_p
N=15
M=10

@contextmanager
def work_with_dummy(N, M):
    dummy = None
    try:
        dummy = lib.get_dummy(N, M)
        yield dummy
    finally:
        lib.cleanup(dummy)

with work_with_dummy(N,M) as dummy:
    internal = (ct.c_double * M)
    # Dest is allocated in python, it will live out of the with context and will be deallocated by python
    dest = (DOUBLE_P * N)()
    for i in range(N):
        dest[i] = internal()
    lib.copy(dummy, dest)

#dummy is not available anymore here. All the C resources has been cleaned up
for i in dest:
    for n in i:
        print(n) #it segfaults reading more than the length of the array
```

What can I change in my python code so that I can treat the array as a list?
(I need only to read from it)

Comment: And there's no way you can provide an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a 2D-array? I would doubt that and not look closer into  your code until I spot such. Anyway - whenever one passes MxN arrays between modules written in different languages, laying them out as a flat array of M*N size and passing along a shape tuple makes life often substantially easier.

Comment: There is no "array of array" in your code.

Comment: @Olaf Thank you . Now we can all wonder: "did he meant multidimensional array and posted some code he made up at the moment to confuse people, or did he wrote a title to give a general context and posted the real code used?" I'm sure a lot of people will struggle to understand that what it's really used is an array of pointers to an array of pointers to an array of doubles. 13 words vs 3

Comment: So apparently you are not even aware there are quite some differences between a 2D array/"array of arrays" and a pointer to pointers. Or C and C++, btw. - your code is not C.

Comment: @Olaf, are you adding something to this discussion or are you just trolling? My code is C++, but I'm externing as C so that doesn't make a difference to Python. I could be writing in D, Rust, my-fancy-language-I-wrote, as long as the conventions are the same it doesn't matter.
And I specified in may previous comment that it is an array (of pointers to array){2}, but the title need to be concise to let people understand what we are talking about. And it looks like it works, since you read the title but still know we are not talking of 2D arrays

Comment: All your code-snippets are C++. None would compiler as C. How about providing a [mcve]? And no, you must not use unrelated tags. Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @decltype_auto I added what you asked. I can't use a 1D array as I would have to either 1) copy the 1D data into lists of lists in python, so to extract the data I would need to copy it twice or 2) build a full wrapper over the 1D data to show it as a 3 level of indirection array, which would be error prone, cumbersome, and probably useless as I'm pretty sure python can do that for me

Comment: @Olaf is it better now?

Comment: On the Python side I'd use `dest = ((ct.c_double * M) * N)()` to have a convenient sized array. Then to pass this to C create `dest_p = (DOUBLE_P * N)()` and initialize it using `for i in range(N): dest_p[i] = dest[i]`.

Comment: @eryksun It works! But we are copying the pointer to the arrays right?
So if we have a M=1, N=1000, we are copying 1000 pointers.
In my real case, I actually have a double***, so it would mean way more copies. Do you want to write that as an answer, so we can maybe expand it and I can accept it?

Comment: Depending on your use case you might instead want to slice the pointer in a list comprehension to create a list of lists. For example, using the previously defined `dest_p`, you could use `[i[:M] for i in dest_p]`, where the `i[:M]` slice returns a list.

Comment: @Makers_F: "I would have to [...] copy the 1D data into lists of lists in python". Nope.

Comment: My comment was for your existing C code, but you may want to consider changing the code to use plain old C contiguous (row major) multidimensional arrays. This is what you'd have, for example, if using a NumPy array.

Comment: @eryksun I'm liking your first suggestion the most. In my NxMxP array, P >>NxM, so copying NxM pointers can be feasible, in exchange for the easiness of programming. I'll look if changing the copying code can work in order to use contiguous arrays. But I can not change the code in the class

Comment: @eryksun Could you please copy your comments in an answer, so that I can accept it. You solved my problem, and I believe it to be fair to give you the rep you deserve!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 3 ways to pass a int** array from Python to C and back

**So that Python knows the size of the array when iterating**

---

**The data**

This solutions work for either 2d array or array of pointers to arrays with slight modifications, without the use of libraries like numpy.

I will use int as a type instead of double and we will copy source, which is defined as

```
N = 10;
M = 15;
int ** source = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    source[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * M);
    for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
    {
        source[i][j] = i*N + j;
    }
}
```

---

### 1) Assigning the array pointers

**Python allocation**

```
dest = ((ctypes.c_int * M) * N) ()
int_P = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
temp = (int_P * N) ()
for i in range(N):
    temp[i] = dest[i]
lib.copy(temp)
del temp
# temp gets collected by GC, but the data was stored into the memory allocated by dest

# You can now access dest as if it was a list of lists
for row in dest:
    for item in row:
        print(item)
```

**C copy function**

```
void copy(int** dest)
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(dest[i], source[i], sizeof(int) * M);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

We first allocate a 2D array. A 2D `array[N][M]` is allocated as a 1D `array[N*M]`, with `2d_array[n][m] == 1d_array[n*M + m]`.
Since our code is expecting a `int**`, but our 2D array in allocated as a `int *`, we create a temporary array to provide the expected structure.

We allocate `temp[N][M]`, and than we assign the address of the memory we allocated previously `temp[n] = 2d_array[n] = &1d_array[n*M]` (the second equal is there to show what is happening with the real memory we allocated).

If you change the copying code so that it copies more than M, let's say M+1, you will see that it will not segfault, but it will override the memory of the next row because they are contiguous (if you change the copying code, remember to add increase by 1 the size of dest allocated in python, otherwise it will segfault when you write after the last item of the last row)

---

### 2) Slicing the pointers

**Python allocation**

```
int_P = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
inner_array = (ctypes.c_int * M)
dest = (int_P * N) ()
for i in range(N):
    dest[i] = inner_array()
lib.copy(dest)

for row in dest:
    # Python knows the length of dest, so everything works fine here
    for item in row:
        # Python doesn't know that row is an array, so it will continue to read memory without ever stopping (actually, a segfault will stop it)
        print(item)

dest = [internal[:M] for internal in dest]

for row in dest:
    for item in row:
        # No more segfaulting, as now python know that internal is M item long
        print(item)
```

**C copy function**

```
Same as for solution 1
```

**Explanation**

This time we are allocating an actual array of pointers of array, like source was allocated.

Since the outermost array ( dest ) is an array of pointers, python doesn't know the length of the array pointed to (it doesn't even know that is an array, it could be a pointer to a single int as well).

If you iterate over that pointer, python will not bound check and it will start reading all your memory, resulting in a segfault.

So, we slice the pointer taking the first M elements (which actually are all the elements in the array). Now python knows that it should only iterate over the first M elements, and it won't segfault any more.

I believe that python copies the content pointed to a new list using this method ( [see sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da2716c447d20d94b625dc823d447d61d796c0ed/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L4346) )

---

### 2.1) Slicing the pointers, continued

Eryksun jumped in in the comments and proposed a solution which avoids the copying of all the elements in new lists.

**Python allocation**

```
int_P = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
inner_array = (ctypes.c_int * M)
inner_array_P = ctypes.POINTER(inner_array)
dest = (int_P * N) ()
for i in range(N):
    dest[i] = inner_array()
lib.copy(dest)

dest_arrays = [inner_array_p.from_buffer(x)[0] for x in dest]

for row in dest_arrays:
    for item in row:
        print(item)
```

**C copying code**

```
Same as for solution 1
```

---

### 3) Contiguous memory

This method is an option only if you can change the copying code on the C side. `source` will not need to be changed.

**Python allocation**

```
dest = ((ctypes.c_int * M) * N) ()
lib.copy(dest)

for row in dest:
    for item in row:
        print(item)
```

**C copy function**

```
void copy(int * dest) {
    for(int i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(&dest[i * M], source[i], sizeof(int) * M);
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

This time, like in case `1)` we are allocating a contiguous 2D array. But since we can change the C code, we don't need to create a different array and copy the pointers since we will be giving the expected type to C.

In the copy function, we pass the address of the first item of every row, and we copy M elements in that row, then we go to the next row.

The copy pattern is exactly as in case `1)`, but this time instead of writing the interface in python so that the C code receives the data how it expects it, we changed the C code to expect the data in that precise format.

If you keep this C code, you'll be able to use numpy arrays as well, as they are 2D row major arrays.

---

All of this answer is possible thanks the great (and concise) comments of @eryksun below the original question.

Comment: I'm using int** because it's a more common case than double, and when looking for solutions it might be easier to find. Changing the type is a question of substituting int with the type you need

Comment: For option 2 you could create a list of arrays instead of a list of lists, e.g. `inner_array_p = ctypes.POINTER(inner_array);` `dest_arrays = [inner_array_p.from_buffer(x)[0] for x in dest]`. Be careful about deleting the original `dest`. Given the way it was created, its `_objects` dict is all that's keeping the row arrays from being deallocated.

Comment: Actually it should be ok to delete the reference to `dest`. In Python 3 `dest_arrays[0]._b_base_._objects['ffffffff'].obj._b_base_` is a reference to the source `dest`. In Python 2 it's `dest_arrays[0]._b_base_._objects['ffffffff']._b_base_`, without the intervening `memoryview` instance.

Comment: @eryksun Update the answer to show your solution. I wouldn't dare to put an explanation as I'm not too sure of what's happening. I guess that with from_buffer we are creating a view over the array, but since we are using a pointer you put [0] to get the address at start of the array.
From your last comment I guess there is no need to store dest so that we don't free the memory when it gets GCed, but in case it's needed we can put store it as `dest_arrays._original_source = dest` so that when dest_arrays gets collected both dest_arrays and dest get deleted

Comment: An element of the original `dest` is a pointer. All ctypes data objects have an associated buffer, which for a pointer is the 4 or 8 bytes of the target address. `inner_array_p` is a pointer type, and like all ctypes data types it has the `from_buffer` class method to initialize an instance using Python's buffer protocol.  So what I did is basically a pointer cast, but without requiring the FFI call that `ctypes.cast` would use. I then dereference the pointer to get an `inner_array` instance, which through a convoluted path keeps a reference back to `dest` and its `_objects`.

Comment: Note that `dest_arrays[0]._b_needsfree_ == 0`, so these array instances don't own the memory. That's why they have a reference via `_b_base_` back to the supporting object that does own the memory. If the owner's reference count drops to 0, the memory is deallocated and anyone using it will likely either see invalid data or cause a segfault.